# django error in displaying data and displaying it on map?

Tags: postgis, geojson, geodjango

.
i am trying to display a feature queried from postgis. . i also designed a user input field to enter the id of the desired feature to be displayed. . i have already queried the attributes first before displaying the feature polygon. .  and the attributes were already displayed on the template. .however, while fetching the polygon, i got error. .

i do not know why this happens. .i have already displayed it before but not querying it by id, i have already displayed the whole shapefile from the postgis. .

This is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from vectorformats.Formats import Django, GeoJSON
from Apps.models import Butuan_Parcel, AGAO
def search(request):

query = request.GET.get('q')
try:
    query = int(query)

except ValueError:
    query = None
    results = None


if query:
    results = Butuan_Parcel.objects.get(id=query)
   # obs = Butuan_Parcel.objects.all()
    context = RequestContext(request)

s_layer = Butuan_Parcel.objects.filter(id=query)
s_feat = Django.Django(geodjango='geometry', properties=['barangay'])
s_geo = GeoJSON.GeoJSON()
s_parcel = s_geo.encode(s_feat.decode(s_layer.transform(3857)))

# for ob in obs:
#     if query is not ob:
#        return render(request, 'noresults.html')
#    else:
return render(request, 'results.html', 'results':results,'s_parcel':s_parcel, 's_layer':s_layer}, context_instance=context)
```

and this is my results.html

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;

    function init(){

    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map',{
            });


       base_layer =  new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OpenStreetMap");

       map.addLayer(base_layer);
/****************************map style********************************************/
    var styleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap(OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults
    (
            {
                fillColor: "yellow", fillOpacity:0.25, strokeColor: "red"
            },
    OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style["default"])
    );
/****************************Vector layers********************************************/
    var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Butuan",{
        styleMap:styleMap
        }
    );

    map.addLayer(layer);
    var format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();

    {% for i in s_layer %}
    var feat = format.read({{i|safe}});
    {% endfor %}

    layer.addFeatures(feat);

/****************************map properties********************************************/
    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(13976068.3513, 995715.692078),11);
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
   }


</script>
</head>

<body onload = "init()">

    <div id="map"></div>

{% block content %}

<form method="get" action="/search/">
<table>
    <tr>

        <td>Search Barangay:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="q" id="id_q" value="{{ query }}"/></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Search" /></td>

    </tr>
</table>
<br/>


<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>:</td>

        <td>{{ results.id|safe }}</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Barangay</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td>{{ results.barangay|safe }}</td>
    </tr>

{% for i in s_layer %}
  {{ i }}

{% endfor %}
    </table>
</form>




{% endblock %}

</body>
```

i tried to display whether my s_layer has data or not, that is why i have

```
{% for i in s_layer %}
  {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

and this displays a right data. .
MAUG
and when i tried to display    `{{ s_layer }}` this gives me 
[< Butuan_Parcel: MAUG >]

when i code `{{s_layer|safe}}` i just have [] as the output.. .

on the other  hand, i used

```
{% for i in s_layer %}
    var feat = format.read({{i|safe}});
    {% endfor %}
```

so that real data could be parsed into geojson and be displayed in the map. . however, there was no vector layer displayed on the map. . these code chunks I have are seen on the whole code above. . i cannot display this vector layer.

Can someone give me hints on how to display this on the map?

I got a screenshot and this is the output
[image]

I wanted to display the output such as this..
[image]

Comment: You said you got an error "while fetching the polygon." What is the error? Please copy/paste the output.

Comment: when i entered "24" on the search textbox, the output displays as ID:24, Barangay:MAUG, this data is queried thru __results__ = __Butuan_Parcel.objects.get(id=query)__ and I tried to query its corresponding polygon thru __s_layer__ = __Butuan_Parcel.objects.filter(id=query)__ . so when i tried to display __{{s_layer}}__ to know if have fetch data, it prints __[<Butuan_Parcel: NONG-NONG>]__ only, when i put __{{s_layer|safe}}__ it just prints [].

Comment: when i code __{%for__ __i__ __in__ __s_layer__ __%}__ __{{ i }}__ __{% endfor %}__ I got an output MAUG. . therefore when i parse this data into geojson i put '{% for i in s_layer %}
    var feat = format.read({{i|safe}});
    {% endfor %}' but there was no polygon displayed on the map. . how would i do that?

Comment: `[<Butuan_Parcel: NONG-NONG>]` is the object representation in Python of a [GeoQuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/). Django doesn't have a way of represent this object in the template language. You need to access the underlying attributes (geometry, in this case) in formats that can be serialized to text; [here is a list of the built-in output formats with GeoDjango](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#geometry-output).

Comment: hi @Arthur actually i did  `s_layer = Butuan_Parcel.objects.filter(id=query)

s_feat = Django.Django(geodjango='geometry', properties=['barangay']) 
s_geo = GeoJSON.GeoJSON()
 s_parcel = s_geo.encode(s_feat.decode(s_layer.transform(3857)))` 
this code is to retrieve that polygon from the postgis using the parameter (actually, it's a user input). i used vectorformats to do the geojson conversion. however, i did not display the polygon . . what could be the problem?

Comment: Can you include the model definition for ` Butuan_Parcel`?

Comment: hi there. . I got it fixed. . ^.^
Actually i got this code out of the loop `var feat = format.read({{i|safe}});` and it worked. . you can find this code above at the results.html. . I hope this also can help anybody out there with the same error as mine. .

Answer (score 1):

I see a typo in your code on the `return render ...` you have a closing } that does not open anywhere (missing { ).